# Removing or Renaming Shared Folder in Localhost after changing Drive Letter

Tags: windows, localhost, shared-directory

Before asking this question, I already checked [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/887890/delete-shared-folder-connection-on-windows).

After I changed the drive letter from E to F, I cannot access to a shared folder in localhost because a shared folder cannot find E drive. I re-shared the folder in F drive, but I couldn't have the same name for new shared folder, because the previous shared folder is still in localhost.

Therefore, I tried to remove previous shared folder using `net use \\localhost\{folderName} \delete` but it failed with the error message: `System error 21 has occurred The device is not ready.`.

1. Should I change a drive letter again and remove shared folder? Can I access to shared folder if I revert my driver letter?
2. Is there any other ways to remove shared folder or rename shared folder which is not ready or not accessible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

1. Right click on My Computer
2. Click Manage
3. Go to Shared Folders
4. Right click on the folder you remove
5. Click Stop Sharing

I hope this helps other people who have the same issue.